# How to evaluate JavaScript in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am looking through the JavaScript debugger in Firebug. This is new to me.

Is there any way to enter a simple statement and evaluate it? For example:

```
console.log(typeof someVar)
```

or simply:

```
alert(typeof someVar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute commands within Firebug you can use the [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line), which is located within the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel):

[image: Command Line in Firebug 2.0]

For longer scripts you can use the [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor), which you can enable through the little arrow ([image: Command Editor toggle button]) at the right side of the Command Line:

[image: Command Editor in Firebug 2.0]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think this is the actual answer.  It's not perfect but may work in most cases:

open up firebug, and click "Script" tab (not Console).  Click "Watch" on right hand side if not selected, and click New watch expression...  - you'll get an input line where you can run *ONE LINE* of javascript... not what I really want, and it's designed to continue to execute in order.

IF you want to write a function on the fly and then test it, this will not work.  So I humbly offer the following coding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#indicator').click(function(){
var state=$('#jsConsole').attr('class');
$('#jsConsole').attr('class', state=='jscon'?'jscoff':'jscon');
});
});
function jsEval(x){
try{
eval(document.getElementById(x).value);
}catch(e){
var v1=''; var v2=''; var v3=''; var str=''; var descr=false;
for(j in e){
if(j=='stack' || j=='number')continue;
if((j=='message' || j=='description') && descr)continue
if(j=='description' || j=='message')descr=true;
str+=(j+': '+e[j])+"\n";
}
if(str) alert(str);
}
return false;
}
</script>

<textarea id="test" class="tw" rows="3" name="test"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="jsEval('test');" value="Test" name="Submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to click the "Console" tab.

Comment: Why wasn't it correct? "Console" tab includes textbox that you can type javascript code to execute. And there's no answer below.